# Clicking a Button in Google Chrome using JavaScript (Tampermonkey extension)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tampermonkey

**What I am trying to do**

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to code button 1 so that when it is clicked, button 2 is also clicked. (This function/ button 1 click is running completely fine as I have tested it multiple times.) The problem is that button 2 is not clicking for some reason.

**What I have tried**

I have tried using this code

```
window.deactivateAutoBuyer = function() {

    document.getElementsByClassName("btn-standard increment-value")[0].click();

    window.autoBuyerActive = false;
    window.notify('Autobuyer Stopped');

}
```

However, the only result I get is the notification that says "AutoBuyer Stopped".

**HTML Code for the button**

```
<button class="btn-standard increment-value"></button>
```

Comment: Why don't you call button 2's function instead of clicking button 2?

Comment: what do you mean by call button 2's function?

Comment: I'm assuming there are two functions. One is called by button 1 and the second is called by button 2. If you want button 1 to "click" button 2 so button 2's function can run, instead just directly call button 2's function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the function associated with button 2 or you can use an event listener on the first button to then click the second button.

```
const button1 = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-standard increment-value")[0];
const button2 = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-standard increment-value")[0];

button1.addEventListener('click', () => { button2.click() });
```